# Eclipse git project messed up

Tags: java

I imported a project from a `git URI` however in eclipse it shows as a files system instead of packages.

[image: [1]]

How can I fix this so the project can be exported as a jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that 1) you are looking at the wrong root directory. That is looking at "src" instead of "Java Resources" (or something like that), and so not getting the packages you expect, or 2) The project doesn't have either the java or, more likely, the Maven builder loaded.

If your copy of Eclipse doesn't have a builder configured (like Maven (m2e)), then when you check out the project, it doesn't populate the way you expect.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to right click on the project itself and go down to "Add Project Natures" and select "Java". If it's already a Java Project, and it just misconfigured the build path, right click on src/main/java and do Build Path -> Use as Source Folder.